# Upload HUGE file > 2GB to nodejs (n Firefox)

Tags: node.js, file-upload

I've made my example as basic possible. I try to upload a huge file, more than 2 GB, to my server but I receive an error **only in Firefox**. In Chrome seems to work allright. It says something like "Error: Connection broken". Could someone explain me why and what could I do about it?

```
var http       = require("http");
var url        = require("url");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    switch(url.parse(request.url).pathname) {
        case "/":
            displayForm(request, response);
            break;
        case "/upload":
            response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
            response.end(
                '<h1>File Uploaded!</h1>'
            );
            break;
    }
}).listen(1234);

var displayForm = function(request, response) {
    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
    response.end(
        '<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">' +
            '<input type="file" name="uploadFile">' +
            '<input type="submit" value="Upload!">' +
        '</form>'
    );
};
```

**EDIT**: I just realized it only happens in **Firefox**, not in Chrome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such large files I recommend you to read your file with `FileReader`, chunk it on small binary pieces with `Blob` or `Blobbuilder` and transfer (by Socket.io) the file chunk by chunk with progress bar, concatenating the chunks on the server. When last chunk is sent - you got full file on your backend.

You can also save current chunk number in cookie/LocalStorage in case of connection breaks to continue transfer.

P.S. For ancient IE's and other shit there is flash plugin for using Blobs, google it.

P.S.S Max file size by POST requests for different browsers: http://motobit.com/help/scptutl/pa98.htm

Comment: In my sample, as you see, Im not even reading them. Its an issue with the transmission

Comment: I tried your code on my local Mac, it worked without error, but it took about ~3-5 minutes to complete.

Comment: If you run the server in the same machine where you open the browser, yes, because theres no actual http. Its all a simple move operation in the hard drive. Try accessing the webpage from another computer.

Comment: Yes, I was able to reproduce that. It's trouble of Firefox, look here: http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/pa98.htm

Comment: If you need Firefox for files more than 2GB, try to read it with FileReader and send them chunk by chunk as I proposed.

Good luck!

Comment: I used sources from here https://github.com/Miserlou/DirtyShare for my personal project. It's very easy to install and test, try if it will work for 2+ GB files. That project is used for browser to browser transfer, but it has nodejs server side for streaming. With very simple modifications this backend can be used for uploading instead of streaming.